# Python error, Popen

Tags: python

trying to use deadpool_dca from [this repository](http://github.com/SideChannelMarvels/Deadpool) and i get this message i can't understand for the life of me.

```
>>> from deadpool_dca import *
>>> T=TracerGrind('whitebox')
>>> T.run(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "deadpool_dca.py", line 300, in run
    oblock=self.get_trace(i, iblock)
  File "deadpool_dca.py", line 460, in get_trace
    output=self._exec(cmd_list, input_stdin)
  File "deadpool_dca.py", line 312, in _exec
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

any help would be much appreciated, completely new to python

Comment: THIS repository https://github.com/SideChannelMarvels/Deadpool

Comment: Looks like it tries to execute [`/usr/local/bin/Tracer`](https://github.com/SideChannelMarvels/Deadpool/blob/3b8dabcdc93e67f6652a6da3138d70441a86bc58/deadpool_dca.py#L36), which seems not to exist on your system. Looks like you need to have [this](https://github.com/SideChannelMarvels/Tracer) installed in the right locations (or fix the paths).

Comment: Could be, I&#39;ll try asap edit:don't think this is it, for TracerPIN uses that path, for TraceGrind uses valgrind that is in the bin folder